# Yii2 GridView Client-Side Filter & Pagination

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I'm working in an application that have large amount of data, it depends mainly on searching and filtering across the GridView.
Server side behaviour decreases search speed, also I wants to filter as you type.
Is the GridView can be customised to be client side?